# XML-RPC library for C++

Tags: c++, c, xml-rpc

What libraries are available for writing xml-rpc clients in native C++ or C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check out either [xmlrpc-c](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/) or [xmlrpc++](http://xmlrpcpp.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: the xmlrpc-c library didn't work for me (using Windows XP and Visual Studio 6)
alas the xmlrpc++ did work flawlessly (altough they said that it won't work)

Comment: While I had some work in porting, Xmlrpc-c worked fine for me on two real-time operating systems, and its support for Linux is fine.  Don't write it off without trying it.

Answer (score 4):

I found a [list of xml-rpc implementations in many different languages](http://www.xmlrpc.com/directory/1568/implementations). Hopefully this list will be useful to others.